# Edge browser is not receving dropdown change event in Selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm struggling with automating dropdown with Edge WebDriver

Driver version 10.0.1586.0

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By dropdownLocator, String optionToChoose) {
  Select select = new Select(getElementWhenPresent(dropdownLocator));
  select.selectByVisibleText(optionToChoose);        
}
```

is **not working with Edge WebDriver** but it **works with IE8-11, Chrome, FF**. Actually dropdown changes its value during test run, but Edge browser ignores this. Browser/driver bug?

*Edit*

Setting dropdown value with jQuery is also not triggering change event

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By dropdownLocator, String optionToChoose) {
    if(this.getName() == BrowserName.EDGE || this.getName() == BrowserName.EDGE_GRID){
        // Select option with jQuery
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        initializeJQuery();

        String $dropdown = "#" + getElementWhenPresent(dropdownLocator).getAttribute("id");            
        executor.executeScript("$(\"" + $dropdown + "\").val($(\"" + $dropdown + " > option\").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == \"TPI\"; }).val())");


    } else {
        Select select = new Select(getElementWhenPresent(dropdownLocator));
        select.selectByVisibleText(optionToChoose);
    }
}
```

jQuery code that is executed:

```
$("#selectId").val($("#selectId> option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "OPTION TEXT"; }).val())
```

*Edit*

HTML of dropdown element (nothing fancy here):

```
<select class="form-control" id="operations">
  <option value="-1_*">Name 1</option>
  <option value="9_*">Name 2</option>
  <option value="16_B7">Name 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML for the select element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally **resolved it with sendKeys()**, so I'm checking if test is performed on Edge and using sendKeys() meth for setting `<select>` option:

```
public void selectFromDropdown(By dropdownLocator, String optionToChoose) {
    if(this.getName() == BrowserName.EDGE){
        getElementWhenPresent(dropdownLocator).sendKeys(optionToChoose);

    } else {
        Select select = new Select(getElementWhenPresent(dropdownLocator));
        select.selectByVisibleText(optionToChoose);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution only seems to work if you don't have multiple options beginning with the same letter